# leaked window error occur when show progressDialog

Tags: android, android-activity

> MainActivity

I got a error on mProgressDialog.show(); line. All of this is in AsyncTask,Please help me out.And i also perform some uploading operation on background method of Aysnctask

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    res = null;
    count = 0;
    //mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Create_NewsFeed.this, "","Uploading image");
    mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Create_NewsFeed.this);
    mProgressDialog.setMessage("Posting.. please wait...");
    mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
    mProgressDialog.show();
    try {
        // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
        boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";

        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "CodeJava Agent");
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Test", "Bonjour");
        outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),true);

        writer.append("User-Agent" + ": " + "CodeJava").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
        writer.append("Test-Header" + ": " + "Header-Value").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //...
    }
}
```

This is my error log. Please check this out.

```
10-08 12:03:00.185  27823-27823/fourever.textile E/WindowManager﹕ Activity fourever.textile.mainclasses.Create_NewsFeed has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@422e43b0 that was originally added here
        android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity fourever.textile.mainclasses.Create_NewsFeed has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@422e43b0 that was originally added here
                at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:409)
                at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:322)
                at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:234)
                at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:153)
                at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:559)
                at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
                at fourever.textile.mainclasses.Create_NewsFeed$ServiceSync$1.run(Create_NewsFeed.java:440)
                at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4766)
                at fourever.textile.mainclasses.Create_NewsFeed$ServiceSync.onPreExecute(Create_NewsFeed.java:437)
                at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
                at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
                at fourever.textile.mainclasses.Create_NewsFeed$1$1.run(Create_NewsFeed.java:131)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Is this the full stacktrace?

Comment: My guess is that something else caused your app to crash before this message, and this exception is only the side effect.

Comment: where did you `dismiss` progressdialog? and also do http calling stuff in `doInBackground` method

Comment: Can you post the complete code of this Activity? Probably the reason of crash is somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

call your api / asynctask like this ,

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                //api calls .. or use async task here

                                }
                        });
```